# SimpleMappingExceptionResolver - Exception not exposed to view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, error-handling

I'm using [SimpleMappingExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.html) to handling errors, but have a problem to expose `exception` to the view - it is `null`. I made an error in some .jsp on purpose get error. My configuration below. Throwing the same exception in controller works good. Anybody help with that ?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver" p:order="0"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" p:order="1">
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="error"/>
</bean> 
<mvc:view-controller path="/error" view-name="error"/>
```

error.jsp

```
<h2>Error: ${exception.message}</h2>
<c:if test="${exception == null}">NULL</c:if>
```

web.xml

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

That works good:

```
@RequestMapping("/exception")
public void testException() throws Exception {
    throw new org.apache.tiles.definition.NoSuchDefinitionException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to use SimpleMappingExceptionResolver. The solution I ended up with was not very good so I'm keen to see if someone has a better one. Here is where I got mine from:

http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/02/handling-errors-in-spring-framework.html